# How to configure the "most" pager to highlight all matches on search?

Tags: search, highlighting, most

I have been using the "most" pager for couple of years,
but when searching and jumping and navigating between the matches ( with n and p ) the cursor is quite small (I barely notice it), so i'd like to wrap the whole word and highlight from the beginning all matched words.
can somebody suggest me how to do it?

Thank you all!

Comment: This feature is already implemented in the `less` viewer. Is there some features of `most` that are missing in `less`? Otherwise I suggest that you use `less`.

Comment: @roaima, Done :-)

Answer (score 1):

This feature is already implemented in the `less` viewer: to highlight all matches on search.

So I suggest that you use `less`, unless you use some features of `most` that are missing in `less`.

---

See `man less` to find what you can do with `less`.